# play next or previous video in android

Tags: android

How to play next or previous videos on click of next and previous buttons? How to implement the functionality? I am showing the gridview of videos from mediastore.I am able to launch them but I want to play the next or previous videos on click of next or prev buttons.I am able to click on the buttons and I am getting prints also.But I am not getting How to implement the functionality. Can anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the videos by their id or name or something in parameters.
And at onClick start pass these parameters to the player.

Comment: thanks alot I got the list of video ids and through that I got the list of video paths.

Answer (score 1):

Create List of video urls. On Pressing next get url of next position and load video and reverse for previous.

Comment: can please give me a pseudo code to create list of video urls

Comment: @indraja : are you loading video from sdcard or web-service?